# Fullcalendar duplicates event using recurring events and switching between agenda weeks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

I'm trying to add a new recurring event to my calendar and it is properly created and showed in the current week. The problem occurs when I switch to previous or next week, because it duplicates the events.

This is my code:

```
$scope.blocks = {
    color: '#F44336',
    events: []
};

$scope.blocks.events.push({
     title: 'Test',
     start: "10:00",
     end: "10:30",
     dow: [1, 2],
     stick: true
});

$scope.eventSources = [$scope.blocks];
```

If I set an unique value in dow field, works fine but if I set two or three, it duplicates or triplicates the event if I switch to other weeks or I get back to current week even.

If I set stick field to false, the event doesn't appear in other weeks.

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Any ideas? Thank you